# How do I detect in C# whether or not a Word instance has the Save as PDF or XPS add-in?

Tags: c#, pdf, interop, ms-office, add-in

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Visual Studio Tools for Office installed.  I will be interfacing with Word through its PIA.  My target Word version is at least 2003.  Muhimbi has informed me that Save as PDF isn't available in 2003 so what I would like to do is check if it's available in the version installed (2003 and later) and then decide from the result whether I want to use the add-in or not.  TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  'Save as PDF' add-in is not available for Word 2003.

You can try and do a conversion and look at the error you get back. You can also try a [3rd party solution](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html) that has already done all the hard work.

Comment: I see.  I'll revise the question then.  Also, a web-based service isn't possible because my app needs to work in off-line mode.

Comment: Going with "You can try and do a conversion and look at the error you get back."